# My code is giving that error: ./greeting2.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Guys I'm a begginer in learning bash scripting and I don't know what error is that, I'm using the latest LTS of Ubuntu and it's giving that error:
./greeting2.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Hello, what is your name? "
read firstname
echo -n "Thank you, and what is your surname? "
read surname
clear
if [ "$firstname" == "Your name" ] && [ "$surname" == "Your surname" ]
then echo "Awesome name, " $firstname $surname
else echo You are not allowed to go!
```

Comment: Obs. I used # in bin bash

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is a useful resource for finding syntax errors (and other issues) automatically. BTW, to format a code block correctly, put four-space indents before each line -- you can automate this by selecting the text and clicking the `{}` button (not the "Snippet" one, that's for code that can run in a browser only).

Comment: As another aside, parameter expansions should be quoted even when passing them to `echo` -- so `echo "Awesome name, $firstname $surname"` keeps your whole string to echo together as a single argument. Otherwise, if someone gave `*` as their first name, you would see `echo` output a list of filenames!

Comment: (Also, you'll get better compatibility across different shells if you use `=` instead of `==` as a string comparison operator in `[`, as it's the only one standardized as part of POSIX `test`; similarly, it's more portable to avoid `echo -n "something"` in favor of `printf %s "something"`).

Comment: ...btw, as a note for future questions here -- please always try to create a [mcve], the shortest possible code that creates the problem you're asking about. If you can take out the "echo"s and the error still happens, f/e, then *do* take out the `echo`s; if changing the `[ ]` to `true` or `false` still shows the problem, then likewise, do that. Often, the solution becomes clear in the process of creating the simplest reproducer -- but even if it doesn't, it makes a question more likely to be helpful to others, since it's focused narrowly on the problem itself and not the surrounding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing fi at the end

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Hello, what is your name? "
read firstname
echo -n "Thank you, and what is your surname? "
read surname
clear
if [ "$firstname" == "Your name" ] && [ "$surname" == "Your surname" ]
then echo "Awesome name, " $firstname $surname
else echo You are not allowed to go!
fi
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was really helpful, I'm new at the programming bash scripts area, really grateful.